# вывод отладочной информации php на локальном сервере

Tags: php, отладка, openserver

всем привет, пытаюсь разобраться, как на локальном сервере устроить вывод отладочной информации и ошибок, как на скринах ниже [image: результат работы var_dump($_SERVER)][image: введите сюда описание изображения] Пытался менять настройки в php.ini, в разделе xdebug (пользуюсь openserver, xdebug уже включен в сборку), но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Глупый вопрос: а включать xdebug пробовали?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev он включен, само собой

Comment: Ну тогда смотрите в сторону [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) + [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

Answer (score 1):

прошу прощения за собственную невнимательность, в файле php.ini строку `xdebug.default_enable = 1` я раскомментировал, а вот то, что `zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll"` закомментирована, я не заметил. раскомментировал, и все заработало.